# What's the deal with window tint?

Tags: ford, window, restoration, tint

I got a Ford van.

5.4 v8 1998 e150.

It has all kinda of deluxe features on it like power windows and seats.  It even has a seat with a coaxial cable output on it for the vcr.

Anyway... one of those deluxe options they slapped on her on her birthday was window tint... and every damn window is tinted except now the tint has kindof a ripple effect to it and if you run yer finger across it... it makes kindof a crinkly noise a little pieces of it fall off.

I thought to myself well hely I'll just peel it off... it won't be tinted no more, but at least it won't look all tired and uncared for.  So I done grabbed a piece and pulled on it but it just refuses to come off in one piece.

It seems like almost like a nightmare!  like math... like a problem where if you try to pull it off, it pulls off only 5% of it in a zig zag pattern... and then you start over from the beginning so it's impossible to ever get it off.

Why can't it just peel off all in one piece all nice like those see though stickers they put on bathroom scale displays?  Did they do that on purpose?

And how they heyl is anyone supposed to replace it on the front windows... cuz the window goes deep into... into the mystery area deep inside the door panel.

Has anyone out there with a 5.4 v8 Ford e150 had this problem?  And what did you do to fix it?

Comment: Tint is damaged due to UV, so now the adhesion force exceeds the resistance offered by the material.

Comment: There's already a question with an answer on this subject @Bubba.

Comment: I would add that you should peel the film very slowly. It can take a little time for the strands of glue to thin off and break. If it is stronger than the film then the film tears. If you give it time for the glue to stretch it weakens it. As shown in the picture for this answer on [Life Hacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/23094/).

Comment: A Heat  gun makes life easy.

Comment: Hey I just wanted to say that I appreciate y'all.  I still left the tint up though.  All that dang conversion extras all screwed up and layered on top of it... it'll make you pass out just thinkin about getting to the glass.  dang van.